# Список подписчиков метки

Tags: поддержка, предложение

У метки видно, сколько участников на неё подписалось. Ещё можно найти топовых участников по ней. А можно ли где-то просмотреть список именно подписавшихся на неё?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, эта информация недоступна пользователям. Источник: [Shog9, сотрудник компании](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4731311#4731311).

Comment: А почему бы не сделать доступной?

Comment: @Qwertiy, но зачем? в чем тут польза? Позвать конкретного человека в вопрос нельзя, написать в личку - тоже.

Comment: @Nofate, можно будет сравнивать списки подписчиков по разным меткам при необходимости. Например, если возникнет желание их синонимизировать, либо в вопросе выбирать между двумя метками, которые ещё не синонимизировали.